# How to hide topCalc row when exporting to Excel

Tags: javascript, export-to-excel, tabulator

In my webpage there is a Tabulator 4.9 table with a row of calculated values added to the top, resulting from the spec `topCalc:"sum"`.
I have also added a button to export the table to Excel and this works fine. However, in the Excel file I do not want the summation row to be present.

I can of course remove that row in Excel, but I prefer to not export it at all from the Tabulator table. I have tried to remove the row using filters, but that has not been successful.

Is there an elegant way to hide a row of calculated values for the export to Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `columnCalcs: false` for the table's `downloadConfig` property.  For example:

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
  downloadConfig:{
    columnCalcs: false
  }
})
```

http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/download#new-tab